# OutOfMemory error, and no idea how to set up bitmaps

Tags: android, image, button, bitmap, out-of-memory

Sorry if this Question is a bit obvious, but I've created an app, which contains a bunch of customized buttons on the MainScreen. In the beginning, everything worked fine, but then I made something, no idea what, unfortunately I've forgotten what I've done. But now, Im getting this annoying OutOfMemory error, and as I'm not that pro in programming, I'm stuck now in fixing this. I've tried setting up Managing Bitmap Memory, also downloaded the Sample App, but I got lost in there, i didnt even found something that looked like a mainscreen.

I've tried to put this code fom the developer site in my MainScreen.java, but I think this is not the way it works:

```
//.......old code(not important)........
```

I would be happy if someone could help me, I'm stuck for like 3 hours on this problem.

**UPDATE**

I'm trying now to scale down all my images and as followed by this ([Android dev link](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html/%20%22android%20dev%20link)) I'm this far (following code is from my MainScreen, which is my mainactivity):

```
    //....................
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView1, options);
            int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
            int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
            String imageType = options.outMimeType;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hiscr, options);
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sharebutton, options);
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.buttongame, options);
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.buttongame1, options);
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_start, options);
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_start2, options);
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_start3, options);
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_start3locked, options);
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_start2locked, options);
            }
    //.........up there i'm trying to decode all my stuff, It contains buttons.xml , images and imageviews. 

//..................In the code below I'm trying to get the downscaled pictures.
      public static int calculateInSampleSize(
                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
        //...............
```

Can i use the decodeResource for everything, like listed above for customized buttons in xml, pictures.png in the drawable folder, and imageviews in the layout.xml ?

And after all it's not working, i'm still getting the outofmemory error.

Comment: can you scale your bitmap and then set it to the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't load all your images at once if you don't need them. Also, use `bitmap.recycle()` to remove your bitmap and save memory when you are done with the bitmap. Do you need every button icon?

Comment: Yes, I need all the picture at once, as it's the mainscreen, from where the user can locate to several other activities.

Comment: You could make a spritesheet

Comment: To scale it just use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap();